# What does "Scale Past 7 Figures" mean?

Tags: meaning

11 Mindset Shifts You Need to **Scale Past 7 Figures**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale - in technology, particularly software. To be able to handle increased load without changing the design of the system.

7 figures - million dollars.

To scale past 7 figures - to be able to increase business revenue or profit beyond a million dollars (without significant change to business model)